# Access a proxy behind NAT

Tags: networking, router, vpn, proxy, raspberry-pi

my situation is this :

I have few Raspberry PIs running some Linux and each of them has LTE USB modem plugged in. All this raspberrys are connected with ethernet to a single router, that has internet access. However, the router is behind ISP NAT and doesnt have public IP. [Diagram 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SECiu.png)

My goal is to create HTTP proxy out of each raspberry,that can be accessed from internet. The client cannot use VPN, only HTTP proxy.

My first idea was to create VPN network and inside it will be all the raspberry and some server instance(e.g. EC2) with public IP. The instance will host multiple http proxy endpoints (accessed by url 1.2.3.4/proxy1..n). The raspberrys are inside VPN, so the server instance can address them as a local network device. Then each time a user would send a web request, it would go to a server instance, then inside VPN, to a selected raspberry and continue outside VPN to internet using the LTE modem.[Diagram 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgAkO.png)

Is this possible ? How to configure the server ? What SW to use on the server and raspberry ? Is the VPN really needed ?

Thank you.

Comment: HTTP proxies don’t have URLs. They have an IP address and a port. So, no. But why not just connect to the VPN from the browsing device?

Comment: HTTP proxies do have URLs and ports. IP address is not the only way. Abou the VPN - the client can use only proxy, I added that to the question

Comment: No, they don’t. You cannot specify a path when the request is `GET http://www.example.com/ HTTP/1.1`. You cannot even use the `Host` header because it’s not for the proxy but the destination server.